# Python Beginner: Setting a variable in a subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x

Working through a beginner course to Python and currently on classes. As an example, the book is using descriptions of Cars/Electric cars to explain classes and sub-classes, etc.

Here is the code:

```
class Car():
    ''' A simple attempt to represent a car ''' 

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        ''' Initialize attributes to describe a car '''
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0

    def car_description(self):
        ''' Return a neatly formatted descriptive name '''
        long_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.make + ' ' + self.model
        return long_name.title()

class ElectricCar(Car):
    # When we put (Car) in the class definition, a child class is created with the attributes of Car.
    ''' Represents aspects of a car, specific to electric vehicles. ''' 

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        ''' Initalize attributes of the parent class. '''
        super().__init__(make,model,year)
        self.battery = Battery()

class Battery():
    ''' A simple attempt to model a battery for an electric car. '''

    def __init__(self, battery_size=70):
        ''' Initialize the battery's attributes.'''
        self.battery_size = battery_size

    def describe_battery(self):
        ''' Print a statement describing the battery size. ''' 
        print("This car has a " + str(self.battery_size) + "-kWh battery.")

    def get_range(self):
        ''' Print a statement about the range this battery provides. '''
        if self.battery_size == 70:
            range = 240
        elif self.battery_size == 85:
            range = 270
        message = "This car can go approximately " + str(range)
        message += " miles on a full charge."
        print(message)

my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla','model s', 2016)
print(my_tesla.car_description())
my_tesla.battery.describe_battery()
my_tesla.battery.get_range()
```

In the class Battery(), the method get_range shows two possible battery sizes (70 and 85), along with their respective ranges.

In the **init** for Battery, the battery size is by default set to 70 kWh.

How would I call on Battery() to set the battery size to 85 kWh for a vehicle?

Comment: Can't you just do `battery.battery_size = 85`? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: You should _always_ include the version-agnostic `python` tag.

Comment: That what what I was looking for, yes. Still trying to get used to calling different classes. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give it the value:

```
self.battery = Battery(85)
```

The default values are used only when there are no values passed into the function, otherwise, the arguments that are passed are used.

And as @jasonharper suggested, you can add a parameter to the `ElectricCar`'s `__init__()` method that specifies the battery size:

```
def __init__(self, make, model, year, batterySize):
    ''' Initalize attributes of the parent class. '''
    super().__init__(make,model,year)
    self.battery = Battery(batterySize)
```

Comment: You might even want to add an additional parameter to ElectricCar's `__init__()` that specifies the battery size (and is NOT passed on to the superclass's `__init__()`).

Comment: Good suggestion @jasonharper, just included it, thanks.